# Manually installing drivers on Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, terminal, drivers, make, uart

I am currently trying to install a driver through terminal.  It is for the USB UART XR21B1411 serial port adapter.  I installed it in the past, but cannot remember how I did it.  Here is a link to the driver: https://www.maxlinear.com/content/document.ashx?id=21651
As you can see, there is a Makefile, two .h files and two .c files.

How might I install this driver?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

From the readme file:

```
Installation
------------

* Compile and install the common usb serial driver module

    # make
    # insmod ./xr_usb_serial_common.ko
```

Which means: Open a command prompt; switch to root context (the # prompt), execute `make`, then execute `insmod` with the provided command line.

If I'm a bit abrupt here, I apologize, but you are going to find a lot of similarly abbreviated instructions while you're working in Linux.

Comment: Yes, I already completed those steps.  I am in the root context and when I try to execute 'make', I get the following message:  "No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop."

Comment: And you are in the directory where the zip file was unpacked? Because there is a makefile in that zip, and if you are in that directory make should have found it. Switching to root context with `su -` will also change your current directory to root's home.